# Apply MLP on unknown dataset?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, mlp

I am working on a simple ML using the example from [Iris](https://rdrr.io/cran/RSNNS/man/mlp.html) MLP.

This example is relatively straight forward since it is to train and test the model. However, the example do not show how to apply the trained MLP model onto an unknown dataset to predict the class for this unknown dataset (which in this case, the flower type).

I have searched for a few hours but could not find any useful website that says how to apply the trained MLP onto the unknown dataset. I did assume that `iris <- splitForTrainingAndTest(irisValues, irisTargets, ratio=0.15)` will be changed to `iris <- splitForTrainingAndTest(unknownirisValues, irisTargets, ratio=0.15)` and be fed into a new `mlp()` but it does not make much sense.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Page 32 of the reference manual on CRAN,
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSNNS/RSNNS.pdf
the examples show a predict generic method for a rsnns object, i.e. a trained model.

Is this what you're looking for?

[image: ref manual]

Comment: Unfortunately no. This is what I mentioned in my post with the same exact Iris example. This page shows the model using known data to train the model. What I do not understand is how do I use my unknown data to put into a trained MLP model.

Comment: What happens when you put the test (unseen) data in place of the train data ? Throws an Error?

Comment: It does not throw an error but it does not make sense. If unknown data is feed into `splitforTrainingAndTest`, then essentially you are training the MLP with unlabel data, no?

Comment: haha, i think there is some confusion just.  I haven't actually used this package so thanks for bringing to my attention.  but you split your data into train and test *both are labelled*. You can then send train data to mlp() and send test data to predict()

Comment: Yes, that is the original example. This will mean that my MLP is trained and I can use for unlabel data correct? How will I be able to do that?

Comment: can you provide a reproducable example or code with data of where you are going wrong or what your outputs are?